# Windows in Ubuntu 20.04 dropping to background

Tags: 20.04

Since doing the upgrade route from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS, when I have windows open in front of a browser, for example, the windows will continually drop behind the browser window. It seems to happen when I move the mouse cursor across the border of the focused window.

Comment: Although it is solved, the problem is not clear to me. Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi he meant to say that windows de-focused when he moved the cursor out of the border of the current windows.

Comment: That's correct. If you're in a window positioned over a full-screen browser, moving the cursor off the smaller window makes the smaller window disappear and brings the browser into focus instead. If you minimize the browser you find the smaller window hiding there. It's essentially an "auto-focus" issue. It's annoying and confusing to have that turned on so I imagine that not many people use the feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. In Gnome Tweaks there's a setting: Windows > **Focus on Hover**. Changed to: **Focus on Click**.

After the upgrade, I must have changed it not knowing what it would do.